# Querying on Json data type in postgres Rails-4

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.2, hstore

I am using Rails-4, have a Product model and stored specifications as JSon type

In Migration file, add 
`add_column :products, :specifications, :json`

sample product record is look like

`#<Product id: 1, prod_id: 525141, cat_id: 6716, category_id: 5, updated: "2013-09-24 07:37:20", created_at: "2014-03-07 12:21:34", updated_at: "2014-03-07 12:32:36", eans: ["4016032274001"], skus: ["DK-1511-010F/WH"], account_id: 2, specifications: {"network"=>["PCI-Express 2.1 16x", "CardBus", "PCI-Express 3.0 16x", "PCI 64-bit, 66MHz", "PCI 64-bit, 33MHz", "PCI 32-bit, 66MHz", "PCI 3.0", "PCI 2.3", "PCI 2.2", "PCI-X", "PCI-Express 16x", "PCI-Express 8x", "PCI-Express 4x", "PCI-Express 2.0 16x", "PCI-Express 1x", "PCI", "PC Card", "ISA", "AGP 8x", "AGP 4x", "AGP 2x", "AGP 1x"], "rating"=>[4]}>`

I want to query on product's Specification.eg: get all products that rating(inside specifications) equals to 4.

Is any gem available to implement this?

Comment: Used Serian gem - Manual implementation. Planning to move elastic search instead of manual.

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of jsonb in Rails 4.2 with Postgres 9.4, you can do this IF the rating field is a string and not an integer. Below is an example.

```
Dynamic.create(payload: {"rating"=>['4']})
Dynamic.create(payload: {"rating"=>['3']})
Dynamic.where("payload -> 'rating' ? '4'").count
```

This will give you the proper records. You will have to update your json field to jsonb. You can do this by following my response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343231/how-to-use-jsonb-in-rails/27630492#27630492).

You can find out more about how to work with [jsonb in Rails 4.2 here](http://robertbeene.com/rails-4-2-and-postgresql-9-4/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is JSONQuery with is implemented in Rails via this Gem: https://github.com/jcoglan/siren