# how to use jsonb in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.4

I have a rails project with Postgresql 9.4  as backend. I have column like this:

```
t.json :slot_details, null: false, default: {}
```

How do I change this to JSONB from JSON? Should I add index and that will be changed to JSONB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is it how it worked with Rails 4.2

```
t.jsonb :slot_details, index: true, default: {}
```

The answer above threw errors for me.

Comment: Can you post your error? I ran that migration up and down to confirm it was working for me.

Comment: @Robert The error was something like unable to cast string to json or something like that.

Comment: My migration only works for json to jsonb. Was your field a string - not json?

Comment: It was a json but did not work so I ended up doing what I did

Answer (score 7):

For migrating this, you can do the following. Payload in this case was originally a json field.

```
  class AlterJsonbToJsonAndBack < ActiveRecord::Migration                      
    def up                                                                     
      change_column :dynamics, :payload, 'jsonb USING CAST(payload AS jsonb)'  
    end                                                                        

    def down                                                                   
      change_column :dynamics, :payload, 'json USING CAST(payload AS json)'    
    end                                                                        
  end
```

To find out how to query jsonb in Rails 4.2, checkout [this article](http://robertbeene.com/rails-4-2-and-postgresql-9-4/)

Comment: will this delete the data?

Comment: This does not delete the data. It converts json to jsonb.