# Select Distinct in Postgresql erroring on unrelated column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.4

I'm struggling to write an SQL statement that does the following: Grab the most recent completed assessments of a group of users

- One per user (distinct `user_id`)
- Of a chosen group of users (`user_id` in array)
- Only completed assessments (`type_name` is not null)
- With all fields (will use later)

Closest attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user_id), assessments.*
FROM assessments
WHERE
  user_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,10)
  AND type_name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  created_at DESC,
  user_id DESC
```

Current error:

> could not identify an equality operator for type json

On:

```
assessments.*
```

I've run through a lot of different versions of this getting various errors, but this one I think should work but it seems to be trying to be distinct based off of all the columns instead of just `user_id`.

I'd really like it to work in Rails, but since I couldn't get that, I thought getting the plain SQL to work first.

**UPDATE**

Part of the problem could be that I have JSON columns on assessment. But since I'm using distinct on just `user_id`, it should ignore those JSON columns

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Assesment.uniq(:user_id)
          .where(iuser_id: [1, 2, 3])
          .where
          .not(type_name: nil)
```

Update:

Since the problem is really in other columns than I would recommend to cast all your `json`  columns to `jsonb` (pg 9.4 magic)

```
  class AlterJsonbToJsonAndBack < ActiveRecord::Migration                      
    def up                                                                     
      change_column :assessments, :column_name, 'jsonb USING CAST(column_name AS jsonb)'  
    end                                                                        

    def down                                                                   
      change_column :assessments, :column_name, 'json USING CAST(column_name AS json)'    
    end                                                                        
  end
```

[how to use jsonb in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343231/how-to-use-jsonb-in-rails)

Comment: I get the same error as before, I'll update the question to provide some more relevant data

Comment: Rails seems to be ignoring the argument in `uniq`. I also tried `distinct` but the query it translates to is:

`SELECT DISTINCT "assessments".* FROM "assessments" WHERE "assessments"."user_id" IN (1, 2, 3) AND ("assessments"."type_name" IS NOT NULL)  ORDER BY "assessments"."created_at" DESC`